# The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. Request Method: POST

Tags: python, django

The problem appears when I submit the form. A few days ago it worked, I changed nothing in this code, but now it fails. Is it possible that different module makes that part of code crashed?
Traceback:

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/new/

Django Version: 1.7.3
Python Version: 3.4.0
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mojblog',
 'users')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/marta/django/djangovenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  130.                                  % (callback.__module__, view_name))

Exception Type: ValueError at /users/new/
Exception Value: The view users.views.create didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from users.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.models import Profile


def test(request):
    return HttpResponse('users!')


def create(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        new_user=User()
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, instance=new_user)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user=form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.is_active=False
            new_user.save()
            return redirect("users:new")

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'users/create.html', {'form1': form})


    # else:
    #   return HttpResponse("something")        

def activate(request, key):

    profile=Profile.objects.get(secret=key)
    user=profile.user
    user.is_active=True
    user.save()



    return render(request, 'users/activate.html', {})
```

Comment: Did you saying `HttpResponse("something") ` is not working.?if yes, it is on `else` condition of `POST`.So if `POST`, it will not execute.OR to be indented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `create` view, if the request is a POST but the form is not valid, the code does not return anything.

Rather than have a separate GET block, you should use the standard pattern:

```
if request.method =="POST":
    form = ...
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
        return redirect(...)
else:
    form = ...
return render(request, 'users/create.html', {'form1': form})
```

In this case the final return catches that case, and re-renders the form so that it displays the errors.

Comment: I tried to fix it in that way, it is still showing the same error.

Comment: Show your exact updated code (as an edit to the question) and the full traceback.

Comment: That's not quite what I posted: your final line in your create function needs to be moved one indent to the left.